# HTML5 Notification in google chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, notifications, chromium, html5-notifications

I saw a link http://dangercove.github.com/html5-notifications/. Here plain-text-type notification works in google chrome (version 23). But html-type notification is not working. I tested it in chromium browser (version 17). Both content-type are working. Why the html-type is not working in chrome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML5 notifications with HTML have been deprecated:

[See this tutorial](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/notifications/quick/)

[See the spec](http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/desktop-notifications/api-specification)

Since this is draft it's all subject to change, such as you are experiencing now. I know, it's sad.

Comment: Instant deprecation? That was a short life.